# SDL Renderer won't render anything

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am trying to draw text to a window and to do that I need a renderer. The only issue I have is that no matter what I do no renderer will draw anything. If anyone has any suggestions on what to change post them. Here is my main function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //initializations
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLTEST", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);    
    SDL_Surface *display = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    
    //our surfaces
    SDL_Rect plz = {200, 200, 50, 50};

    //colors
    SDL_Color color = {255, 255, 0};

    //text
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("Grand9k_Pixel.ttf", 25);
    SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "TESTING", color);
    if (surf == NULL) {
        printf("%s", TTF_GetError);
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);

    //main loop
    bool quit = false;
    while(quit == false) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT ||
            (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT &&
            event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 1, 255, 1, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &plz);
        //SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &plz);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        //SDL_Delay(1000 / 30);

    }   

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_QUIT;
    return 0;
}
```

So I was trying to make the background green but that didn't work. I removed a good portion of the components beside some necessary ones and that didn't fix anything. I tried making it use software rendering. I tried changing the names of things and changing if things were pointers. I have tried removing as many variables of failure as possible and still nothing.

Comment: `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` is incompatible with `SDL_Renderer`, choose one. When I removed the former, it started to work. Also why did you remove the `#include`s? This just creates a tiny bit more work for anybody who wants to help you.

Comment: thx for the feedback and solving my problem, in future I will include the #includes.